# HumanTaskEventListener: is it possible to view the task output?

Tags: wso2, bpel

I am using a HumanTaskEventListener in WSO2 BPS to save task results to a database. Because WSO2 does not support outcomes, I return the outcome in the task output. 
I need to retrieve this outcome in the TaskEventListener - but is this possible? I only seem to be able to query the simple task details, but not the output...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

received an answer from Tobias Unger: 
https://gist.github.com/hasithaa/5648471